# element hover overlapping element

Tags: jquery, hover, tooltip, mouseover, mouseleave

I'm trying to get a tooltip effect with jQuery and it isn't working exactly the way I want it to.

```
$(".product").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find(".description").fadeIn(300);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".description").stop().fadeOut(300);
});
```

`.product` is the parent element, `.description` is the child element.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/saTNB/3) is the page I'm working on. I need the tooltip (`.description`) to remain visible if I hover it. I've been successful in getting that to work, **however** if the tooltip overlaps the coordinates of another parent element (`.product` triggers the function after all), it disappears.

Can anybody nudge me into the right direction? I've read up a lot here on stackoverflow but although there are many similar questions, those suggested solutions don't seem to work for me. Can any kind soul help a JavaScript idiot here?

Comment: Try `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`?

Comment: @otakustay thanks for the suggestion, but `mousenter` will fail here as the function will then not apply to any inner element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `z-index` to your tooltip to something `999999`:

```
<dd class="description" style="opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 999999; ">
    Avocado op een bootje van rijst en zeewier
    <span class="social">FB | Twitter</span>
</dd>
```

Make sure to have the z-index for `dd.description` higher than those images.

Comment: thanks, your suggestion works. I tried Z-index 500 on `.description` before, but that didn't seem to work, even if I set `.product` on 100. Any idea why?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, browser stacks every element based on z-index and rest of them go at the end how they put in the page. So you must be having more than 400 elements floating across the page which might be causing the issue. It's always good to set the highest value to such elements.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is unbind the `mouseleave` function when the mouse enters the `.description`, and rebind it when the mouse leaves the `.description`. Although it might be simpler (and less buggy) to just use a tested tooltip plugin (there are a ton).

Comment: I was going along that road too, but I didn't manage to wrap my head around it. But adjusting the Z-Index like codef0rmer suggested seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `position:relative` on `dd.productWrap`

Your `<dl>` has `display: table-call`. This prevents `position:relative` from applying too it

Comment: `position:relative` is used on `.product` here with the intent to keep `.description` `position: absolute` in reference to `.product`. If I didn't specify that, the tooltips would show up at the top of the page, so it's working fine :)

Comment: So what's the problem? You JS works fine, but tooltips are shown at the top of the page. I thought that was the problem, isn't it?

Comment: it's not displaying properly? the tooltip should be **under** `.product`, not at the top of the page. Works fine here? @caligula

Comment: in FF 14.0.1 when I hover on product (e.g. in 8-th row) a tooltip is shown at the top of the page

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I'm gonna take a look at it in a minute